# Instantiate a \Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to use the method `match(\Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface)` of  `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack`.

But I don't find any way to get the request I'm searching for.

[This articles](http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/zend-framework-accessing-request-object-from-anywhere/) says how to get a request object outside a controler. I'm searching for an equivalent with ZF2

Comment: What do you mean? It is an interface, you can not *construct* it, it already exists. You might want to create a class that implements it? Is that what you mean with "construct"?

Comment: I want to be able to call the match() method of TreeRouteStack and the zend documentation doest explain how to implement the RequestInterface

Comment: Well because that is common, basic PHP OOP fundamentals. You can read about interfaces and how to implement them here: http://php.net/interfaces

Comment: Yes but if i dont know the methods i have to implement from RequestInterface I wont be able to do it ! Moreover I'm not sure I really have to implement it. I think there is Zend object which allready implements it that i could use.

Comment: You can inspect the interface with http://php.net/reflection , here an example for the `ArrayAccess` interface: http://eval.in/4931 - also you can read the source-code, e.g. https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/RequestInterface.php

Comment: I did browse the Librairy directly and RequestInterface is empty... Only a namespace, some comment for license and an empty body of the interface

Comment: See the extends? That means it is build upon, https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/MessageInterface.php - Using the said reflection will tell you that as well. Good luck. Don't get lost. And take care.

Comment: BTW you can savely just start to create a class implementing. PHP will throw you exceptions if you have missed something and tells you with which function.

Comment: In fact i realised that i'm searching for an equivalent of that : [link](http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/zend-framework-accessing-request-object-from-anywhere/)

Comment: Take care, looks like that is ZF1, but you are here referring to ZF2.

Comment: Yes it is the problem. ZF2 is not welly documented for now !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to fix by browsing the unit testing of the zf2

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/tests/ZendTest/Mvc/Router/Http/TreeRouteStackTest.php

The `Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request;`  will give a valid Request for the match method

```
 use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request as PhpRequest;
 /*TreeRouteStack*/
 $request = new PhpRequest();
 $stack->match($request);
```